# jquery -- how to set one radio button based on another getting clicked

Tags: jquery, radio-button

Let's say I have a form that includes this:

```
<input type='radio' name='o37_field1' value='aaa'>aaa
<input type='radio' name='o37_field1' value='bbb'>bbb

<input type='radio' name='o44_field1' value='aaa'>abcdef
<input type='radio' name='o44_field1' value='bbb'>baksdf

<input type='radio' name='o58_field1' value='aaa'>wisdof
<input type='radio' name='o58_field1' value='bbb'>safhwr
```

Here's what I need to do with jquery but am having trouble:

If "aaa" is clicked on with in one of the sets, also set/check "aaa" for the other ones, and do the same for any other radio buttons that have "field1" as part of the name and "aaa" as the value.

Ditto for bbb

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will set all radios with a value of "aaa" when one is checked:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(':radio[value=aaa]').change(function(){
       $(':radio[value=aaa]').prop('checked',true);
   });
});
```

The more robust solution like selecting all "like" values when one is clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(':radio').change(function(){       
       $(':radio[name$='field1'][value='+$(this).val()+']').prop('checked',true);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. http://jsfiddle.net/5p8KN/ with [`endswith attribute selector`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) to select field1.

```
$("input[type='radio']").click(function(){
$("input[type='radio'][name$='field1'][value='" + $(this).val() + "']").prop('checked',true);
});
```

if you want to look for [contains attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) for field1 match then you can use `input[name*='field1']`

Answer (score 0):

apply same class to all aaa radio buttons

then in click event use

```
$("input[type='radio']").click(function(){
  $(":radio[value="+$(this).val()+"]")).each(function(index,value){     
    $(this).attr('checked',true); or   $(this).attr('checked','checked');
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to do it with just the html I have? I think the way the current code is set up it would be problematic to do what you suggest, or at least I'm hoping I wouldn't have to redo the code to be able to have such a shared class name.