# How to change radio button to 'checked' when another is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, attributes, radio-button

I hope you guys can help me with this one.

How can I have a radio button **id="A"** change it's attribute to **'checked'** when radio button **id="B"** is selected?

Radio buttons A and B are in different groups.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16116596/jquery-how-to-set-one-radio-button-based-on-another-getting-clicked

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="A">Radio A
<input type="radio" name="group2" id="B">Radio B
<input type="radio" name="group2" id="C">Radio C

$("input[type='radio'][name='group2']").change(function() {
  if ($('#B').is(':checked')) {
    $('#A').prop("checked", true);
  } else {
    $('#A').prop("checked", false);
  }
});
```

Here is the jsFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/8kdb7d6o/

Comment: Billy thank you so much for your help. This almost solves my situation. Now, how can I have #A get unchecked if user deselects #B?

Comment: Is radio B in a radio group?

Comment: yes, in a different radio group than A....... The whole idea is selecting B checks A & B, deselecting B unchecks A & B.

Comment: I updated the answer and the jsFiddle. Let me know if this solution is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#B").change(function(){
    $("#A").prop('checked', true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

to check if radio input checked or not

```
if($('#B').is('checked')){
   $("#A").prop('checked', true);
}
```